# Waiting for an ajax call to finish

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery's sortable to resort a list.  The items are numbered so I'd like to be able to indicate the new numbers as well after the resort.  Originally, I reloaded the page after doing the sort.  However, I've just "discovered" ajax and find that it's a potentially much cleaner solution.  My code almost works except for one issue.  When the page is first loaded before the sort, a bunch of span tags are hidden; after I do my ajax call, however, they become unhidden, and I'd like them to remain hidden.  I've tried:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/main_scripts/sort_chapters_and_sections.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: newOrder,
                success: function(thing_reordered){                                            $(".inline_link_list").html(thing_reordered);

$("span").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class').match(/\bspan_hidden/)){
         $(this).hide();
    }
});
}
});
```

However, after the call, my span_hidden tags become unhidden.  My guess is that the ajax call isn't completed yet so that my "span_hidden" tags are not yet in the browser and subsequently, there's nothing yet to hide.  If I could understand how to ensure that the ajax call is completed finished, I can test this theory out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the if statement seems wrong.
moreover you don't need to use each() for such a simple search.

just try:

```
$('.span_hidden').hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback;  I actually need the more complicated version because they're of the form span_hidden_1, span_hidden_2, etc.  Regardless, I'm not sure what the issue is with the "if" statement...

Comment: my bad, the "if" is ok. could you explain further what happens to the span tags after the ajax call? what you mean with "they become unhidden"? are they the same tags or they get replaced?

Comment: No worries!  Basically, when the page originally loads, all of my "span_hidden" tags are hidden (after $(document).ready(....); they become unhidden if the user clicks on certain links.  So, the "default" is to hide everything.  Then, when I do the ajax call, and reorder some stuff on page, the "span_hidden" tags are no longer hidden.  (I left out an important line in my code above which successfully replaces some html on the page with "thing_reordered"). My thought was that "thing_reordered" -- the html with the span_hidden tags -- is not quite loaded yet and hence, there's nothing to hide.